# How to slice a vector in c++ and assign to itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, vector, subset

I would like to know how I can replace the contents of a vector with a subset of that vector, without re-allocating a new vector (every question I have found appears to have the purpose of allocating a new vector)

example:

```
vector<int>* testVec = new vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
//do some operation to slice vector, to say {2, 3, 4} without re-allocating
//testVec should now have contents {2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: Take a look at eric nieblers ranges and views: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3 Might be what you want.

Comment: erasing first and last element?

Comment: Don't use `new` like this, ugh. :(

Comment: Be aware that not all solution are equivalent in case an exception is thrown and this might have an impact on which one you should use.

Comment: By the way, it does not make much sense to want to avoid extra internal allocation while you have external allocation... You fail to make trivial optimization and want to do probably useless optimization.

Comment: @Phil1970 I think in this case it is more efficient and more elegant to do it in-place. Allocating new list and moving elements will make the code-reader think more, instead of just erasing both sides of vector (which is the answer I've accepted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not clear on the usage scope, but two calls to `std::vector::erase` would suffice and don't incur any reallocation.

For your example:

```
std::vector<int> testVec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
testVec.erase(testVec.begin() + 4, testVec.end());
testVec.erase(testVec.begin(), testVec.begin() + 1);
```

By first removing the tail of the vector you can make sure the values are only moved once.

[Here is the full code](http://ideone.com/T8OnGm).

Note that I assumed that you don't actually need to use a pointer to `std::vector`.

Comment: Erase at the end can be achieved by calling `resize` with argument less than current size. In this case `resize(4)`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot but this will incur a reallocation and moving/copying the remaining elements. ;-)

Comment: no, it will not reallocate, as it would invalidate iterators, and it can do that only if capacity changes (resize was called with argument larger than current capacity).

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot upon reading the doc once more it appears you're right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use a read/write approach:

```
int wp = 0; // "write ptr"
int rp = 0; // "read ptr"
for (auto& x : v) {
    if (... i want to keep element x, index rp ...) {
      if (rp != wp) v[wp] = std::move(x);
      wp++;
    }
    rp++;
}
v.resize(wp);
```

this kind of scheme works also for filtering on conditions that depend both on the index and on the element value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `std::rotate` and `vector::erase`

```
void slice(vector<int> & v, std::size_t start, std::size_t size)
{
    assert( v.size() > start + size );
    std::rotate( v.begin(), v.begin() + start, v.end() );
    // Vector is now {2,3,4,5,1}
    v.erase( v.begin() + size, v.end() );
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, after the rotate, you can just use `resize` to reduce the size.

Comment: On second thought, this is not a particulary efficient solution. `rotate` will copy/move elements that are going to be deleted on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the parts you don't want:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vec.erase(vec.begin() + 4, vec.end());
vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little function that takes a predicate.

For every element of the container that passes the predicate, the element is erased from the container.

No reallocation is done, and each element is `std::move`'d at most once:

```
template<class C, class F>
void erase_if( C& c, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = std::remove( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f) );
  c.erase( it, end(c) );
}
```

Doing this with indexes is a bit tricky.  If the indexes are contiguous, you can just rotate the first one into the first position, then erase the tail end of the container, or erase the tail and the front, or a number of myriad ways.

If they are not, you basically have to write a manual version of `std::remove` that works on indexes instead of on element values.

It would probably work if you had a "counting" test function that kept count of which elements it was called on, but relying on the order that the test function is called on seems overly fragile.  And `remove_by_index` is easy enough:

```
template<class Begin, class End, class Test>
void remove_by_index(Begin b, End e, Test t) {
  auto writer = b;
  auto reader = b;
  std::size_t index = 0;
  while (reader != e) {
    if (t(index)) {
      ++reader; ++index;
      continue;
    }
    if (reader != writer) {
      *writer = std::move(*reader);
    }
    ++reader; ++writer; ++index;
    continue;
  }
  return writer;
}
```

giving us:

```
template<class C, class F>
void erase_by_index( C& c, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = remove_by_index( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f) );
  c.erase( it, end(c) );
}
```

Suppose you want to keep the slice of all even position elements:

```
erase_by_index( vec, [](auto i){return i&1;} );
```

or suppose we want to keep an interval:

```
template<class C>
void keep_interval( C& c, std::size_t start_index, std::size_t length ) {
  erase_by_index(c, [=](auto i){ return i < start_index || i >= (start_index+length); } );
}
```

---

Now a more generic way would consist of creating an alternative view of your container, where each element in the view corresponds to some range of elements in your original container, doing tests on that view, then applying the operation back on the original container.

Not sure how to write that succinctly.