# trim array to elements between i and j

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, trim

A classic, I'm looking for optimisation here : I have an array of things, and after some processing I know I'm only interested in elements i to j. How to trim my array in the fatset, lightest way, with complete deletions/freeing of memory of elements before i and after j ?

I'm doing mebedded C++, so I may not be able to compile all sorts of library let's say. But std or vector things welcome in a first phase !

I've tried, for array A to be trimmed between i and j, with variable numElms telling me the number of elements in A :

```
A = &A[i];
numElms = i-j+1;
```

As it is this yields an incompatibility error. Can that be fixed, and even when fixed, does that free the memory at all for now-unused elements?

A little context : This array is the central data set of my module, and it can be heavy. It will live as long as the module lives. And there's no need to carry dead weight all this time. This is the very first thing that is done - figuring which segment of the data set has to be at all analyzed, and trimming and dumping the rest forever, never to use it again (until the next cycle where we get a fresh array with possibily a compeltely different size).

Comment: Is the data in a raw array or is it in container like a vector?

Comment: For now it's an array of more compliacted objects, but I am open to changing to a container if it implies easier trimming and other handling

Comment: Well a vector should be just as easy to use as a raw array.  It also allows what you want to do by writing 2 lines of code.  If that works then what you want is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575163/how-to-slice-a-vector-in-c-and-assign-to-itself

Comment: I have to make sure vectors are ok in my build. Seems that they still move things in this solution though ... And I have *many* things, so I just want to ignore the first few and last few

Comment: It is a shame you can't use any libraries.  [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) would be right up your alley.

Comment: Yeah, we can't all have our own little libraries, otherwise the final executable will be too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions about speed your millage may very based on the size of the array you're working with, but:

Your *fastest* way will be to *not* trim the array, just use `A[index + i]` to find the elements you want.

The *lightest* way to do this would be to:

1. Allocate a dynamic array with `malloc`
2. Once `i` and `j` are found copy that range to the head of the dynamic array
3. Use `realloc` to resize the dynamic array to the size `j - i + 1`

However you have this tagged as C++ not C, so I believe that you're also interested in readability and the required programming investment, not raw speed or weight. If this is true then I would suggest use of a `vector` or `deque`.

Given `vector<thing> A` or a `deque<thing> A` you could do:

```
A.erase(cbegin(A), next(cbegin(A), i));
A.resize(j - i + 1);
```

Comment: Very nice answer, 1) +1 for the "not trim" and pass along an argument saying where to start/end 2) +2 for moving only the head back at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change aloocated memory block size in standard C++ (unless you have POD data — in this case C facilities like `realloc` could be used). The only way to trim an array is to allocate new array. copy/move needed elements and destroy old array.

You can do it manually, or using vectors:

```
int* array = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
std::vector<int> vec {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
//We want only elements 3-5
{
    int* new_array = new int[3];
    std::copy(array + 3, array + 6, new_array);
    delete[] array;
    array = new_array;
}
vec = std::vector<int>(vec.begin()+3, vec.begin()+6);
```

If you are using C++11, both approaches should have same perfomance.

If you only want to remove extra elements and do not really want to release memory (for example you might want to add more elements later) you can follow [NathanOliver link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575163/how-to-slice-a-vector-in-c-and-assign-to-itself)

However, you should consider: do you really need that memory freed immideately? Do you need to move elements right now? Will you array live for such long time that this memory would be lost for your program completely? Maybe you need a `range` or perharps a `view` to the array content? In many cases you can store two pointers (or pointer and size) to denote your "new" array, while keeping old one to be released all at once.

Comment: GAH! **DO NOT DO THIS** you `delete[] array;` and then use it. That's way bad. Fortunately on the second time through the loop this will error. I can only think that you intended to have `delete[] array` *after* the `for`-loop. In any case this requires you to keep the `array` *and* `new_array` open for the duration of your loop. Depending upon the size of `new_array` that may not be viable. Which is why [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37725961/2642059) I suggest you use a `vector`/`deque` to contain your initial array and then resize to fit the range.

Comment: @JonathanMee did you probaly read first post version where I mistakenly placed braces incorrectly? Right now there is no loop at all.